# PyVisa and Agilent 823578 on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, usb, visa, pyvisa, gpib

I am trying to get PyVisa working on my mac. I have installed it and [NI libraries](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download/unpackaged.ni-visa.351229.html) but when I try to run the following simple python file from terminal in VS code:

```
import sys
import pyvisa as visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()

inst = rm.open_resources('GPIB::10::INSTR') #Instrument GPIB Addr = 10
print (inst.query("*IDN?"))
```

By running 'python3 temp.py' I get the following error message:

```
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Insufficient permissions for action: Unable to load 'com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR' in unprivileged request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Insufficient permissions for action: Unable to load 'com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR' in unprivileged request.}
zsh: abort      python3 temp.py
```

Comment: Same problem here but using a C program. However this error reports different errors, sometimes I get a RAID error.

Comment: Does the NIMAX program crash on your mac too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `com.ni.driver.NiViPciK` extension is installed and loaded. For this, go to About This Mac -> System Report -> Extensions (in Software section) and find NiViPciK. It will likely say "Loaded: No". You need to manually allow National Instruments extensions.

1. Boot into recovery mode by holding Cmd-R while powering up.
2. Open Terminal from Tools menu.
3. Execute: `spctl kext-consent add SKTKK2QZ74`
4. Reboot

This did the trick for me:
[image]

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks a lot. How did you find this wizardry?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using NI IVI backend, but lately gave a spin to open source [PyVISA-py](https://pypi.org/project/PyVISA-py/) backend instead and it has worked great for our automation purposes both on OSX and Linux.

I changed
`rm = visa.ResourceManager()` to `rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')`.
Some minor modifications may be needed (I had to remove instrument.clear() calls for some reason).